# SQL Server Express across network

Tags: networking, connection, ssms, sql-server-express

Can SQL Server Express be accessed from another computer running SQL Server Management Studio across the network? Assuming there are no network firewalls etc.

Comment: *By default*, SQL Server **Express** instances do not accept remote connections - but you can enable this by checking a checkbox: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2005/05/05/how-to-configure-express-to-accept-remote-connections/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. But remember that you must accept open to remote or tcp/ip connections

Comment: OK thanks.  I had the connections enabled and the protocol types.  Starting SQL Server Browser from windows services seemed to do the trick.